# Linq<string> 2 lists select without having to foreach

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 lists currently

```
List<string>machines 
List<string>productCodes
List<ProductionData> productionData
```

I need to check the machines and production codes against the productionData list. Is there a way of doing this without having the need to do a Foreach machine and then Foreach productCodes. See code below

```
int productionCount = 0;
var productionData = (from p in Entities.Scrappages
                     where p.Date >= p.Date && p.Date <= p.Date
                     select p).ToList();

List<string>machines = new List<string>();
List<string>productCodes = new List<string>();

foreach (var machine in machines)
{
    foreach (var productCode in productCodes)
    {
        productionCount =
            (from p in productionData
   where p.MachineID.Equals(machine) && .ProductionCode.Equals(productCode)
             select p).Count();

    }
}
```

Is there a way of doing this without the foreach?

Comment: what about a `Join`?

Comment: You probably meant `productionCount +=` instead of `productionCount =` in your inner loop?

Comment: So you want to find the things in productiondata where both the machine and product code is anywhere in their respective lists? ie the list orderings are totally independant of each other?

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
var productionCount = (from pd in productionData
                      join pc in productCodes
                      on pd.ProductionCode equals pc
                      join m in machines
                      on pd.MachineId equals m
                      select pd).Count();
```